Eclipse fragment project localization failed
I have created a eclipse fragment project.The host plugin is org.eclipse.ui,the fragment folder like this:
com.cqyt.ide.nl
  META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
  build.properties
  plugin_zh.properties

The MANIFEST file:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Nl
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.cqyt.fordiac.ide.nl
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: CQYT
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.116.0"
Automatic-Module-Name: com.cqyt.fordiac.ide.nl
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-Localization: plugin

The build.properties file:
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
    plugin_zh.properties

Basically,i want to localiza the eclipse workben window,for example, replace menu File to Chinese lauguage "文件",Part of the plugin_zh.properties file contents like:
category.file.name=\u6587\u4EF6
category.edit.name=\u7F16\u8F91

I have already set launch parameters "-nl zh",but when the window shown,the File menu not changed to "文件".So what's the problem and how can i fix it?

The line Bundle-Localization: plugin seems not correct to me and should be removed: this conflicts with the host bundle/plugin also having Bundle-Localization: plugin. See also here: https://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/latest/index.php#zh (in the ZIP file BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-zh_4.26.0.v20230220105658.zip the JAR eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.nl_zh_TW_4.26.0.v20230220105658.jar which does the same).

Is your launch configuration set to Clear the Configuration area before launching? If you used that launch config before creating your fragment project, not clearing it could be a factor.
